# Appending list with integers

Tags: python, python-2.7, list

I have been trying to create a tiny script that takes scrambled text from a template and finds a location. I have even managed to make it work by trial and error. Problem is.....I don't know how it works. Maybe someone can clarify it for me ?
Here's the code:

```
word_list = """something
Location: City
other_something"""
word_list = word_list.split()
indexes = [(index + 1) for index in range(len(word_list)) if word_list[index] == "Location:"]
location = []
location2 = []
for index in indexes:
    location2 = location.append(word_list[index])
print location
```

After realising that name of the city always comes after the phrase "Location:" I wanted python to find and print the next word. It even works ! Now the part I don't get is why the location2 stays empty. To my understanding it should be equal to location. Or not ? Why the answer stays withing the Location ?
Please note that I am a complete beginner so an answer that won't be very simple might be beyond my comprehension.

Comment: `some_list.append(some_value)` works in-place and returns `None`. I'm not sure what you expected it to return, but then `location2` is simply repeatedly set to `None` in the loop.

Comment: Can you perhaps show an expected output? It's unclear what you want to return from this code.

Comment: It simply should return 'City'. What would you use instead of .append ?

Comment: There is nothing wrong with using .append in this case, as juanpa.arribillaga said, .append is adding word_list[index] to the list called location, but it doesn't return anything, so it doesn't really make sense to say location2 = ... What do you want location2 to contain, if it is simply a copy of location, you could also write location2.append(word_list[index]) for example.

Answer (score 1):

```
I hope this makes sense, this code is a bit wacky.

# This line of code assigns a value to the variable word_list
word_list = """something
Location: City
other_something"""
# This line makes a list from the words, with each item in the list being one word
word_list = word_list.split()
# This line loops the variable index over the range of the word_list, and if the index's value is "Location:" it stores
# index+1 into a list called indexes
indexes = [(index + 1) for index in range(len(word_list)) if word_list[index] == "Location:"]
# This makes an empty list called location
location = []
# This makes an empty list called location2
location2 = []
# This loops over the indexes in indexes
for index in indexes:
    # This line of code never stores anything to location2, because location.append appends to the list called 
    # 'location', and since location.append does not return a value to store, location2 remains empty
    location2 = location.append(word_list[index])
# This line prints the list called location.
print location
```

Answer (score 1):

you can take advantage of a list's `.index()` attribute,

```
word_list = """something
Location: City
other_something""".split()

print word_list[word_list.index('Location:')+1]
```

this will simply print `'City'` in this situation. `index()` returns the index of the element specified by the first argument. By adding one to the index of `'Location'`, you can access the next element of the `word_list`, which will always be the location if the format of the `word_string` does not change.

Comment: Yes, that really helps. Thank you for providing an answer and fixing my newbie code :)